# How do you find the Main Window thread in UWP?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, uwp, synchronization, task

I have a library that needs to call the main windows thread in UWP when it receives a message from a communication channel (let say, a message indicating a check box should be checked).  The library saves a copy of the SynchronizationContext when it starts up, so it can Post back to it when the data comes in, but the trouble is, I'm not guaranteed that the caller of this library is on the main thread when it's initialized.

Is there some simple, guaranteed way to obtain the Main Window Thread (that is, the Windows' SynchronizationContext) so I don't need to rely on the caller to make sure the contexts aren't switch?

Comment: Use [Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher) and the ``RunAsync`` method

Comment: The **CoreDispatcher** is a WindowsUI concept.  I'm looking for the **SynchronizationContext** which I can reference in a .NET Standard library.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to push something onto "the main window thread" will fail eventually when you pick the wrong window / thread. A better design is to have the library expose an event and then any consumer (including the main window) can listen to that event and do the appropriate thread marshalling (if any) for itself.

If you absolutely must get "the main window" then `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow` will do it.

Comment: *Trying to push something onto "the main window thread" will fail eventually when you pick the wrong window / thread* - That statement makes absolutely no sense.  There is only **ONE** Windows UI thread.  Please explain a scenario where I could pick the wrong one.

Comment: There is one thread *per window*. Note this implies there can be zero, one, or many threads... so you might crash (`null` deref), you might get the wrong window, or you might get lucky.

Comment: There is one thread for the entire UI.  I have never heard of this theory of one thread per window.  You wouldn't happen to have a URL you can reference, would you?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury see [the Multiple Views sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=620574) for a case where a single UWP app has multiple UI threads. If you always go to the main view, then you will be on the wrong thread if your intent was to communicate with a secondary view.